# ElasticSearch - Update multiple documents at once with a WHERE clause

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSearch 6.2.2 on Linux - all activity achieved via API calls - we don't have Kibana set up.

I am trying to update one field of approximately 5,000 documents to be the same value. Right now I only know how to update one document at a time, using the following API call:

**Url:**

```
POST http://{{elasticip}}:9200/{{index}}/_doc/{{docid}}/_update?pretty
```

**Body:**

```
{
  "doc": { "categories": [ "NEWS" ]}
}
```

I have approximately 5k documents with a `categories` value of `null`.  So I need to do an update API call that says update all documents where `categories` field is `null` with value `[ "NEWS" ]`.

Is this achievable via API call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be achieved using the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html):

```
POST your-index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.categories = params.categories",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "categories": ["NEWS"]
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "categories"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Val, thanks for the prompt response!  I was not aware of the update by query API.  This works perfectly!